# How to add hover transition while targeting class with ">"

Tags: css, class, hover, transition, target

I am trying to add transition, but can't make it work. My hover works slightly different, as it is targeting different class to change, it's:

```
.news-thumbnail:hover > .news-description-container{
padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
height: 21rem;  
-webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 2s linear;
-o-transition: all 2s linear;
transition: all 2s linear;
}

Edit: adding original class    

.news-description-container{
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
background-color: white;
padding:2.5rem 2rem;
text-align: left;
height: 15.5rem;
}
```

Which makes this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyeOS.png

Into this when you hover it(news-thumbnail), simply white area(news-description-container) slides up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6mxf.png

How can I make the transition work for this one? I just want it to slide up and down, not appear/disappear without transition.

Maybe I did it wrong and shouldn't do it this way?
Didn't found anything after googling, so it might be useful for others.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction of your problem? The unhovered css of your component should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Here... You can use same style hover transition.

Just change few parameters and thats it...

See code `[Here]`[1](https://codepen.io/samia92/pen/GqVRdo)

Comment: Awesome! This one works for me, just gave it a little tweaks :) Thank You a lot!